# How to copy and process data in the columns based on texts in the Header but header is not in first row

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel and been told that I may find the solution in VBA.
I am working on a system generated report from which I need to remove few columns, but the report contains some important information in first 25 rows. After this information, we get 15 to 40 rows of actual report data (number of rows varies by centres).
I need to process this actual data by removing blank columns, sorting by A to Z, and then inserting the ‘Average’ in the last column. 
Currently, I am copying actual report data, trim down unnecessary columns, make the necessary changes, applying VLOOKUP with last month’s report to verify opening and closing counts are matching or not (they almost always do, but why to take chances?)  and then pasting it at the same location.  Can it be done using VBA?

Format of report

```
     >   For the period  01-11-2011  to 30-11-2011              
     >  *Parameter Selection List                                               
  >From                     01-11-2011
  >Date                     30-11-2011
  > Partner                 SAM
  >Code                     TWO
  >Location                 999
  >Report For               All
  >Code                   : TWO                                 
  >Location :               ABC

  Product Name  |LastCount|AddedInPeriod |Left In The Period |Net Total |   Average     
  SUPER GLUE    |123456   |0             |  0                |  234567  |           
  CRICKET BAT   |345678   |0             |  0                |  346899  |           
  NICON         |2345     |0             |  0                |  2456    |           
  OLD STICKS    |45689    |0             |  0                |  56778   |               
  Total         |517168   |0             |  0                |  640700  |
```

**Product Name** is in Column B, Column C is blank, **Last Count** is in Column D, Header **AddedInPeriod** is mearged in Column D and F but data is in Column F,  same is with **Left In The Period**(Header  is merged inColumn G and H,but data is in column H), Col I is blank, **Net Total** is in J, Col K is blank and **Average** is  in Col L
Data below the headers Product name, Last Counts and Net Total is necessary, rest of the range should be removed. (Please note, few cells are merged)
Final Report should look like this

```
      For the period  01-11-2011  to 30-11-2011 
        *Parameter Selection List                                               
  From                    01-11-2011
  Date                    30-11-2011
  Partner                 SAM
  Code                    TWO
  Location                999
  Report For              All
  Code                   :TWO                                   
  Location :              ABC

Product Name|Last Count  |Net Total|Average
CRICKET BAT |345678      |346899   |346288.5
NICON       |2345        |2456     |2400.5
OLD STICKS  |45689       |56778    |51233.5
SUPER GLUE  |123456      |234567   |179011.5
**Total     |517168      |640700   |578934**
```

How to do that?

Comment: A screenshot of your excel file would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that will get the letter of the column with the header you suggest.

```
Function Letter(oSheet As Worksheet, name As String, Optional num As Integer)
If num = 0 Then num = 1
Letter = Application.Match(name, oSheet.rows(num), 0)
Letter = Split(Cells(, Letter).Address, "$")(1)
End Function
```

just create a new variable, and pass the header to the function, i.e.,

newvar = letter(sheets("Sheets1"), "SUPER GLUE", 4)

where the 4 is, where you indicate the row where the header can be found, in this instance I put row 4. Once you have the letter, then use

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range(newvar & "4:" & newvar & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
```

This will take the information from the particular column, with the column header, and paste it into sheet2 A1

Comment: Can you please explain? I am really new!

Comment: In order to copy by header, you need to get the column letter of where your name is, so let's say "SUPER GLUE" is in column C. You need to create a variable that stores the letter C, because you need the copying range. So if I want to copy C2:C100 then I need the letter function, to retrieve the column letter. Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row is just a way of getting the last row.

Comment: Also you would need to put the function in a different module, or after the end sub. Then when you pass a variable to the function, it will retrieve the column letter.

Comment: TESTED ... THANKS

Comment: I'm delighted to help if the code worked please mark it as the answer! I love this function, I use it all the time at work.